Why is there no mention of the sin of Bitul Torah in the confessions of Yom Kippur
In the confessions on Yom Kippur, there seems to be no mention of the sin of Bitul Torah. There are references to sins that come about through lack of learning but the sin of Bitul Torah itself seems not to be mentioned. Why is this?

סרנו אזנינו משמוע תורה ?לא קבענו עתים לתורה ?זלזלנו בתורה? and if all else fails, this covers everything: כפרנו בכל־התורה כלה :)

Where are these quotes from please??

Viddui Hagadol sefardi YK Machzor https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Yom_Kippur_Edot_HaMizrach%2C_Shacharit%2C_Reader's_Repetition.24

על חטא שחטאנו בבלי דעת

Yes. But that's for the sin which occurred because I didn't learn - not for the sin of not learning.

A few points:
Firstly, Rav Dessler (Michtav Me'eliyahu) interprets the "Al Chets" as root causes of sin, rather than a list of sins per se. With that interpretation, there are several that could account for the sin of Bitul Torah.
Secondly, the confessions are often broad and open to interpretation. So, for instance, interpreting "siah sifsoseinu" as what our lips do talk about, as opposed to what they don't.
Finally, I believe some commentators (The Chid"a springs to mind) have expanded versions of the confession, and I believe Bitul Torah makes the list (unfortunately, don't have it to hand...)

Thank you. Would you like to suggest those "that could account for the sin of Bitul Torah"?

"Prikat Ol" - "We have thrown off... the yoke of studying Torah" (Artscroll comments in expanded Vidui section)

Great answer. The Al Chets that are not actually sins (e.g. Lashon Hara), are generally acts of carelessnesses in relationships, which is an implicit sin (as we should value and cherish our relationships, and tread carefully in them)
